# How to interpret the output of checkgrad function in scipy?

Tags: numpy, optimization, machine-learning, scipy

The expected output of scipy.optimize.check_grad is the the 2-norm of the difference between the gradient and the finite difference approximation of gradient. I am unable to understand from the output whether my gradient is good enough or not. Is there any range in which the values must belong? What is an acceptable error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your gradient function returns a **vector**, lets call it `g`, and scipy numerical method gives you good (although costly) estimate `v`. Now what you get is

```
||g-v|| = sqrt( SUM_{i=1}^d (g_i - v_i)^2 )
```

In other words, it is a square root of the squared errors of your gradient summed over all dimensions. What is acceptable error? Depends on the function and gradient dimension. I would say that eveything above `10e-4` is wrong always. Although answering whether `10e-4` or `10e-10` is ok depends on your particular application - there are different requirements for simple stochastic optimization (which sometimes just needs a **sign** of each dimension rather than the value) and different for exact methods for solving some complex numerical simulations.

Comment: Can you direct towards material that talks about the different requirements (like sign of each dimension rather than the value)?